# NOT EXISTS Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table called "contas" and another table called "cartoes" I need to verify what "IDCARTAO" doesn't exists in table contas, like that: "If I have one conta with cartoes.IDCARTAO = 1, the result needs to be 2 and 3";

```
SELECT cartoes.IDCARTAO 
from cartoes
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 from cartoes
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN contas ON (cartoes.IDCARTAO = contas.IDCARTAO)
                 WHERE contas.IDCARTAO = cartoes.IDCARTAO)
```

Why this sql code doesn't work?

Comment: is CASE WHEN EXISTS()... THEN ... ELSE ... END what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT IDCARTAO 
  FROM cartoes c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM contas
   WHERE IDCARTAO = c.IDCARTAO
)
```

Comment: For sure! Thanks a lot man! I doesn't understand the code, but it's doing what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Tiny tweak: Instead of using `not exists`, try `not in`. As in...

```
SELECT ct.IDCARTAO 
from cartoes ct
WHERE ct.idcartao not in 
  (SELECT c.idcartao from contas c)
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! If you feel so inclined, please mark the question as answered. :)

Comment: Not in tends to be slow.  So, while it's intuitive, it's often a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how it works.
In your case, that query would return all records from the cartoes table where there are no records in the cartas table for the given IDCARTAO.

You already have 3 options up there, If you want to filter records with some specific IDCARTAO(means if you have a static list of IDCARTAO), use *in*. Otherwise I would use the answer from @peterm, because it would be faster when the subquery results is large.

for more reference, please hit [EXISTS Condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php)